# Display content. Bottom of the content on the home screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem**:

display the content, so that was the end of the visible text, and the rest was hidden under the "header".

I will try to portray graphically.

**There are now**:

[image]

**It is necessary that would have been as follows**:

[image]

Comment: Why dont you just reverse the CSS from the header to footer? That will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really see your code but maybe try adding something like this:

```
#header{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:10;
   height:50px;
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
   background:rgba(255, 245, 238, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this [www.geniusamigos.com](http://www.geniusamigos.com/) .

You can do it with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var fixed = false;

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            if (!fixed) {
                fixed = true;
                $('.header2').fadeTo(600, 0);
            }
        } else {
            if (fixed) {
                fixed = false;
                $('.header2').fadeTo(600, 1);
            }
        }
    });

    $(".header").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(600, 1.0);
    });

    $(".header").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(600, 0.3);
    });

});
```

In the site, there are two headers with same style settings. One header's opacity is set to 0.6 permanently. The other header's opacity is changing when scrolling and hovering. And header should be in fixed position.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: It is unlikely, it should be right after the page has loaded.

Comment: Ok, then move the page wrapper up using CSS.

Comment: I think, I've understood your scenario. Try margin-top:-100px; or something. (Add a negative value to it.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're after the sticky footer: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: This should better be a comment. Or you can add some code, and make it a full answer.

Comment: Thanks for that mate, I am still getting used to this.